# changing css of i tag based on value

Tags: jquery, css

how would i go about iterating through the class name student-week-diff and if the value is less than or greater than 0 change the class from student-week-diff to fa-level-up (if greater than 0)and fa-level-down (if less than 0)

Here is my html table, i have defined a class name of student-week-diff

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="studentweek">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Weeks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>VAR (%)</td>
            <td class="text-warning"> <i class="student-week-diff">-10.65%</i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>VAR (diff)</td>
            <td class="text-warning"> <i class="student-week-diff">-13,953</i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>VAR (%)</td>
            <td class="text-navy"> <i class="student-week-diff">8.81%</i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>VAR (diff)</td>
            <td class="text-navy"> <i class="student-week-diff">11,320</i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my trail

```
var test = $(parseFloat('.student-week-diff').text());

$.each (test, function(){
    if (test < 0) {
        $('.student-week-diff').removeClass(".student-week-diff").addClass(".fa-level-down");
    } else {
        $('.student-week-diff').removeClass('.student-week-diff').addClass(".fa-level-up");
    }
});
```

Comment: What's this `$(parseFloat('.student-week-diff').text());`? You **need** `parseFloat($('.student-week-diff').text());`

What's `$.each (test, function){` ? You **need** `$('.student-week-diff').each(function () {`

Comment: i guess i have to iterate through each class and check value and change?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) **Do not post questions repeatedly.** If you need to improve/clarify your previous question, use the "edit" link to do that. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it's a Question and Answer site.